# What's correct catalina_base path for Tomcat installed from the package?

Tags: debian, tomcat, puppet, augeas

I've the following manifest to configure Tomcat to use 8983 port instead:

```
include java
class { 'tomcat': install_from_source => false }

tomcat::instance {'default': package_name => 'tomcat7'} ->
  tomcat::service  {'default':
    use_jsvc => false, use_init => true, service_name => 'tomcat7'
  }->
  tomcat::config::server { 'tomcat7':
    catalina_base => '/usr/share/tomcat7',
    port          => 8983,
  }
```

However when run, I've got the following errors:

```
$ sudo puppet apply -vd tomcat-test.pp
debug: Augeas[server-/usr/share/tomcat7](provider=augeas): Augeas version 1.3.0 is installed
debug: Augeas[server-/usr/share/tomcat7](provider=augeas): sending command 'set' with params ["/files/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml/Server/#attribute/port", "8983"]
debug: Augeas[server-/usr/share/tomcat7](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection
err: /Stage[main]//Tomcat::Config::Server[tomcat7]/Augeas[server-/usr/share/tomcat7]: Could not evaluate: Save failed with return code false
```

Which indicates that Augeas is trying to modify the wrong file (`/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml`) which is in `/etc/tomcat7`.

At [puppetlabs-tomcat GitHub](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-tomcat#defined-types) we can read:

> tomcat::config::server: Configures attributes for the Server element in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`.
>
> `$catalina_base` Specifies the base directory for the Tomcat installation.

which suggest I should have `conf` dir in Tomcat base folder (`CATALINA_BASE`), but it isn't there, as all the configuration is in stored separately in `/etc/tomcat7`.

See: [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/introduction.html).

Is there any way that `puppetlabs-tomcat` module can somehow handle properly the default installed instance of Tomcat? Or I should create a symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `catalina_base` attribute it incorrect, i.e., the `CATALINA_HOME` has been defined instead of `CATALINA_BASE`. Change it to `/var/lib/tomcat7` and run puppet again.

Comment: When upgrading `augeas`, I haven't upgraded `augeas-lense` with it (seems it didn't catch the dependency automatically), now it works:) It probably could work with the older puppet either, however older puppet was printing only limited debug messages about Augeas, the upgraded one showed much more such for example `/augeas/load/Xfm/error = /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/xml.aug:114.21-.35:type error: expected lens but found regexp` which suggested problem with augeas.